# エラー LNK1104 ファイル 'Debug\********.obj' を開くことができません。への対応法について

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

古いVisual StudioのSolutionをビルドしようとしたら、次のエラーが出ました。

「エラー    LNK1104 ファイル 'Debug\********.obj' を開くことができません。」

権限かなと思って、everyone fullcontrolにしてもダメでした。
リンクディレクトリにDebugを指定してもダメでした。

本エラーへの対処法がわかりましたら、教えて頂けないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ここ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx )見ても解決しなさそうです？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーで示された ***.obj について、

(1)自身がコードしたファイル名 +.obj
(2)見知らぬファイル名

(1)の場合は、コンパイル結果が出力されそうなフォルダを検索して見つけ出します。
見つからない場合はコンパイルエラーになっていないか確かめましょう。

(2)の場合は、その*.obj自体がどのようなものであるかを調べてから対処方法を探ります。

まずは、どちらであるか調べてみてはどうでしょう。

> これは(1)になります。「***.obj 」はあるのにコンパイルエラーになっているときがあるわけですね。

いいえ、コンパイルに失敗した場合は*.objは作られません。
成功している場合はとこか(のフォルダ)に*.objが見つかるはずですが、リンカーはその場所がわからないためエラーになるわけですね(プロジェクト\Debugフォルダしか見に行かないので)。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。これは(1)になります。「***.obj 」はあるのにコンパイルエラーになっているときがあるわけですね。調べてみます。